# Find-doc but only return function name

Tags: clojure

I remember reading quite recently about a clojure command that you can run at the repl like `find-doc` but it only returns the function names in a list. Then you can type the number beside the function you want and it will give you the full documentation for that function.

Does anyone know what this is called?

Comment: Perhaps actually an emacs feature.

Comment: `apropos` is definitely from Emacs land.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apropos` returns a seq of function names which you can then feed to `doc`:

```
user=> (apropos "doc")
(find-doc doc *remote-javadocs* javadoc add-remote-javadoc add-local-javadoc *local-javadocs*)
```

Building a `show`-workalike for Clojure functions on top of it would be very simple; I don't think I've seen one in the widely used libraries though.

```
(defn show-fn
  ([s]
    (let [res (sort (apropos s))]
      (dotimes [i (count res)]
        (println (str (inc i) ":") (nth res i)))))
  ([s n]
    (let [res (sort (apropos s))
          r   (nth res (dec n))
          v   (resolve r)]
      (println v)
      (println (:doc (meta v))))))
```

Works like this:

```
user=> (show-fn "doc")
1: *local-javadocs*
2: *remote-javadocs*
3: add-local-javadoc
4: add-remote-javadoc
5: doc
6: find-doc
7: javadoc
nil
user=> (show-fn "doc" 5)
#'clojure.repl/doc
Prints documentation for a var or special form given its name
nil
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found it, it's the `show` function in [repl-utils](http://richhickey.github.io/clojure-contrib/repl-utils-api.html#clojure.contrib.repl-utils/show)

Comment: `show` serves a different purpose though -- it lists members of its argument considered as a Java object.